# Api Gateway and Elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway

I would like to use Elastic beanstalk with Api gateway. I'm using Cognito to manage the authentication and I need to allow the incoming connections to elastic beanstalk only from Api gateway. To solve this problem Api gateway provides a client certificate but I don't know how I can use it on elastic beanstalk.

Is there another way to accomplish it?

Thank you,
Agostino

Comment: Any answer to this question will depend on the actual web server you are using in your Elastic Beanstalk environment. Are you using Nginx, Apache, IIS?

Comment: It is a scalable application with Apache Tomcat

Comment: Do you have Nginx or Apache web server running in front of Tomcat?

Comment: With elastic beanstalk can I choose the load balancer or is it managed by aws?

Comment: The load balancer is an Elastic Load Balancer. The reverse proxy is either Nginx or Apache, dependent on your configuration. To enforce a client-side cert to limit access to only API Gatewway, you would configure your reverse proxy to enforce that cert.

Comment: I want to use the cognito authentication and according to this I have to trust on the incoming request because into the api gateway I add programmatically the cognito identity id. Is the client certificate the only way to accomplish it or is it easier to use the aws service proxy feature of api gataway?

Comment: You can't use the service proxy to hit your Elastic Beanstalk server. The service proxy is only for exposing the AWS API, not any custom APIs you may have deployed to EB. Using the client certificate is the only way to restrict your EB application to API Gateway usage.

Comment: I created a scalable ebs application and I have Apache in front of Tomcat, how can I install the client certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to follow any instructions for installing the client certificate for Tomcat (such as [this blog](http://www.maximporges.com/2009/11/18/configuring-tomcat-ssl-clientserver-authentication/)).

Once you have installed the client certificate on the Beanstalk instances, you will need to setup the ELB in front of your Beanstalk application to use TCP load balancing instead of HTTPS load balancing.